# How do I tell Mutt to ask for a gpg passphrase?

Tags: mutt, gpg

I'm slowly migrating to mutt after years of Thunderbird and stumped by gpg. I have Mutt signing messages by default, but I don't get asked for a passphrase and then the message fails:

```
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: skipped "53453F2E": bad passphrase
gpg: signing failed: bad passphrase
Press any key to continue...
```

How do I get Mutt to ask me for a passphrase if it needs one to sign messages?

Answer (score 5):

What is your configuration? I used a tutorial long ago (sorry, I don't see it now) to get this configuration:

```
# $Id: .gpg-muttrc,v 1.1 2004/01/08 00:22:40 tom Exp $
# mutt commands for GPG
set pgp_sign_as=0xF7E48EDB
set pgp_decode_command="gpg %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --batch --output - %f"
set pgp_verify_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --verify %s %f"
set pgp_decrypt_command="gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose --batch --output - %f"
set pgp_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_clearsign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --textmode --clearsign %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_encrypt_only_command="/usr/lib/mutt/pgpewrap gpg --batch --quiet --no-verbose --output - --encrypt --textmode --armor --always-trust --encrypt-to $pgp_sign_as -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_encrypt_sign_command="/usr/lib/mutt/pgpewrap gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --batch --quiet --no-verbose --textmode --output - --encrypt --sign %?a?-u %a? --armor --always-trust --encrypt-to $pgp_sign_as -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_import_command="gpg --no-verbose --import -v %f"
set pgp_export_command="gpg --no-verbose --export --armor %r"
set pgp_verify_key_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --fingerprint --check-sigs %r"
set pgp_list_pubring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --with-colons --list-keys %r" 
set pgp_list_secring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --with-colons --list-secret-keys %r" 
set pgp_autosign=yes
set pgp_replyencrypt=yes
set pgp_timeout=1800
set pgp_good_sign="^gpg: Good signature from"
```

Given the symptoms, I'd check on `pgp_sign_command`.  But **also** check that your configuration is consistent regarding whether you are using `gpg` or `gpg2`.

Further reading

- [MuttGuide/UseGPG - Mutt](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/UseGPG)
- [Everything You Need To Know To Start Using GnuPG with Mutt](http://codesorcery.net/old/mutt/mutt-gnupg-howto) (looks like the source I used)

Answer (score 4):

Remove `--batch` and `--passphrase-fd 0` and it will ask for your passphrase every time you sign/encrypt.

Comment: On a Mutt 1.12.1 not using `--batch` definitely breaks everything.

Answer (score 3):

This may be an issue in mutt 1.5.24; I just migrated from 1.5.23 and started having this problem as well. The suggestion to remove --batch and --passphrase-fd 0 from gpg.rc fixed this for me.